# Local COM server

Tags: com

I have a C++ `dll` in which I implemented a com interface. This `dll` is loaded in process A and process A is running. I want this process to run as COM local server. `exe` of this process is normal console application.

I have another process B which creates the instance of com class written in dll.
I want to use this instance to call method from the COM class but those method should be executed in process A. Currently they are running in process B.

When I create `exe` from com class and not dll then methods of com class are executing in different process.

But I cant create a separate 'exe' for com classes. I want them in a dll which is loaded in process A at runtime.

Comment: Use Running Object Table to achieve inter-process communication. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17490/Running-Object-Table-Provider-in-NET-consumer-in-M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Running Object Table to achieve inter-process communication. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17490/Running-Object-Table-Provider-in-NET-consumer-in-M